# Multiple slider on page tih toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I have tabs button with coressponding year,when page loaded the active class shoul be on the batton, and show me coresponsind slider. I use bxslider. All work correctly with toggling button and hide and show new divs, but I can not implement multiple bxslider on the page. [codepen](http://codepen.io/palaniichukdmytro/pen/YZqMKx?editors=1010)

```
#awards-bar
  .awards-bar-steps
    .step.step-1.active(data-slider='2016')
      span  2016
    .step.step-2(data-slider='2015')
      span  2015
    .step.step-3(data-slider='2014')
      span  2014

.awards-slider#slider-2016(data-slider='2016')
  p 2016
  ul#slider1
      li
        img(src='http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg')
      li
        img(src='http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg')
.awards-slider#slider-2015(data-slider='2015')
  p 2015
  ul#slider2
      li
        img(src='http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg')
      li
        img(src='http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg')
      li
        img(src='http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg')
.awards-slider#slider-2014(data-slider='2014')
  p 2014
  ul#slider3
      li
        img(src='http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg')
      li
        img(src='http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg')
      li
        img(src='http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg')



$('#slider1').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 322,
        minSlides: 1,
        slideMargin: 10,
        maxSlides: 3,
        // maxSlides: (widthAwardsSlide < 640) ? 1 : 3,
        moveSlides: 1,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        auto: false,
        autoReload: true,
        controls: false
    });
$('#slider2').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 322,
        minSlides: 1,
        slideMargin: 10,
         maxSlides: 3,
        // maxSlides: (widthAwardsSlide < 640) ? 1 : 3,
        moveSlides: 1,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        auto: false,
        autoReload: true,
        controls: false
    });
$('#slider3').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 322,
        minSlides: 1,
        slideMargin: 10,
        maxSlides: 3,
        // maxSlides: (widthAwardsSlide < 640) ? 1 : 3,
        moveSlides: 1,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        auto: false,
        autoReload: true,
        controls: false
    });

$('.step').click(
    function() {
        $('.awards-slider').hide();
        $('.awards-slider').eq($(this).index()).show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two things incorrectly:

1. You are not using a CDN for bxslider.js. You can use `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.9/jquery.bxslider.js`
2. You are not using bxslider.css. You can use `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.9/jquery.bxslider.min.css`

Here is my demo: http://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/NpNQeK?editors=1010

Comment: thanks, how to make active only one, not three at one, 
/* .awards-slider:not(#slider-2016) {
    display: none;
} */ are not working

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. Could you rephrase?

Comment: When page loaded I see all three sliders at once, how to make only active one slider will be loaded.